# Brownie not deploying scripts (deploy.py)

Tags: chainlink

I'm trying to deploy my script, deploy.py. However, Brownie is not letting me - when I do brownie run scripts/deploy.py, it does not work, pointing to a hardhat error. Anyone have suggestions? Also when I go to the project directory, C:\Users\JAVED\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Simple_Titanic_ANN.vscode\Blockchain\BrownieWeb3, it says "ModuleNotFoundError", so I decided to just go to the root directory.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twi2V.png)

Comment: Brownie and Hardhat are separate smart contract frameworks and usually don't work well in conjunction. On top of that, you shared a screenshot of Remix IDE, it would be much helpful if you edit your question and share relevant code snippets, error messages and repro steps.

Comment: Can you watch this video and update your question accordingly after finishing? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XT8STflvwNo